# php <input> and <output> difference

Tags: php, html

When I use POST method to get values of HTML from the form, values from 'input' tags are extracted whereas values from 'output' ones are not. Is there any difference for PHP whether the value is in 'input' or 'output' tag?

Comment: the names should give it away - `input` supply data and `output` are used to display data - they are not passed in any form submission

Comment: so if i want to get data from output i should either duplicate it with hidden input or use input for the sake of output ?

Comment: how are these `output` elements being populated and why would you want to get the data from them when you have already populated them with the data you want to get from them?